# NameNotFoundException While Uninstalling an app in 4.2 emulator

Tags: android, exception, uninstallation

I get NameNotFoundException while Uninstalling any app in 4.2 emulator.Why the Exception is raised while uninstalling??

E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967): getPackageInfoItem() NameNotFoundException
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.winsland.zlibrary.ui.android
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:248)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageInfoItemFactory.updatePackageInfoItem(PackageInfoItemFactory.java:87)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageInfoItemFactory.updatePackageInfoItem(PackageInfoItemFactory.java:66)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.PackageIntentReceiver.onReceive(PackageIntentReceiver.java:56)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2524)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5414)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
E/PackageInfoItemFactory(25967):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: put your code here  and get  your answer !

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when a given package, application, or component name cannot be found.
Check out Android package manager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html